# How can I only autoCreateSchema if database doesn't exist yet?

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I have the following problem:
I'm using DataNucleus with JDO for my program. My jdoconfig.xml contains the following line:

```
<property name="datanucleus.autoCreateSchema" value="true"/>
```

If I start my program now and the database doesn't exist yet it is created and everything works fine.

But if I stop my program and start it again and the database already exists I get errors:
Constraints 'USER_U1' and 'USER_U1' have the same set of columns, which is not allowed.

How can I tell my program to only create the schema if it doesn't exist yet?

Comment: IMPORTANT: I noticed when I remove @unique from the String username variable I don't have this problem anymore. But I WANT the username to be unique.

Comment: Define classes and metadata that produce such a problem